# tkinter, how to get the value of an Entry widget?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to offer the user the possibility to calculate his profit of his projected sales if the margin has a certain value (.23). The user should be able to enter any value as projected sales:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

margin = 0.23
projectedSales = #value of entry
profit = margin * int(projectedSales)

#My function that is linked to the event of my button
def profit_calculator(event):
    print(profit)


#the structure of the window
label_pan = Label(root, text="Projected annual sales:")
label_profit = Label(root, text="Projected profit")
label_result = Label(root, text=(profit), fg="red")

entry = Entry(root)

button_calc = Button(root, text= "Calculate", command=profit_calculator)
button_calc.bind("<Button-1>", profit_calculator)

#position of the elements on the window
label_pan.grid(row=0)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
button_calc.grid(row=1)              
label_profit.grid(row=2)
label_result.grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Initial question _did_ include how to use Entry text as variable as well.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get what's inside Entry widget using `get` method like:

```
entry = tkinter.Entry(root)
entryString = entry.get()
```

Here's an example that does around what you want:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

margin = 0.23

entry = tk.Entry(root)

entry.pack()

def profit_calculator():
    profit = margin * int(entry.get())
    print(profit)

button_calc = tk.Button(root, text="Calculate", command=profit_calculator)
button_calc.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You may also want to use `textvariable` option and `tkinter.IntVar()` class for synchronizing integer texts for multiple widgets like:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

margin = 0.23
projectedSales = tk.IntVar()
profit = tk.IntVar()

entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=projectedSales)

entry.pack()

def profit_calculator():
    profit.set(margin * projectedSales.get())

labelProSales = tk.Label(root, textvariable=projectedSales)
labelProSales.pack()

labelProfit = tk.Label(root, textvariable=profit)
labelProfit.pack()

button_calc = tk.Button(root, text="Calculate", command=profit_calculator)
button_calc.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Above example shows that `labelProSales` and `entry` have their `text` values equal at all times, as both use the same variable, `projectedSales`, as their `textvariable` option.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for your answer, I was hopping for this kind of answer. I think I'm starting to understand !

Comment: Sorry, but here it says as error:

Comment: ```File "interface.py", line 6, in search
    entryString = inputS.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'```

Comment: @TroyD That error is not related to the code piece above as `inputS` variable is _not_ mentioned at all. For further assistance on that error, I'd suggest reading up on https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/